# Streaming json in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

has anyone used the streaming json in nativescript? I found this http://oboejs.com/why but it seems not to work. I'm using nativescript 1.6, any suggestion would be appreciated really much. Thank you.

Comment: A quick look at that library and I noticed a web and node version in the dist folder. Which are you adding to your project? The web based won't with. NativeScript isn't web or browser based. The node might work. I haven't looked through the source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no library to my knowledge currently built for NativeScript that allows streaming JSON.   Just for clarification sake you can easily pull JSON from a server and parse it using the built in fetch/http api's, right now -- but their is no way to have it start parsing the json as it downloads in chunks built in.

You can attempt to modify the npm node module to build for NativeScript.

Or thinking outside the box a bit; you can also use the web based version of that module inside the [nativescript-webworkers](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-webworkers) and have it pull and process your JSON and communicate the json messages back to the NS environment.  The WebWorkers module actually wraps the native platform's web browser module so it can run all browser based JS code.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the open source NativeScript-WebWorkers.